# Use a CASE expression without typing matched conditions manually using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I have a long and wide list, the following table is just an example. Table structure might look a bit horrible using SQL, but I was wondering whether there's a way to extract IDs' price using `CASE` expression without typing column names in order to match in the expression

| IDs | A_Price | B_Price | C_Price | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 23 |  |  | ... |
| B |  | 65 | 82 | ... |
| C |  |  |  | ... |
| A | 10 |  |  | ... |
| .. | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Table I want to achieve:

| IDs | price |
| --- | --- |
| A | 23;10 |
| B | 65 |
| C | 82 |
| .. | ... |

I tried:

```
SELECT IDs, string_agg(CASE IDs WHEN 'A' THEN A_Price
                                WHEN 'B' THEN B_Price
                                WHEN 'C' THEN C_Price
                        end::text, ';') as price
FROM table
GROUP BY IDs
ORDER BY IDs
```

To avoid typing A, B, A_Price, B_Price etc, I tried to format their names and call them from a subquery, but it seems that SQL cannot recognise them as columns and cannot call the corresponding values.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT IDs, IDs||'_Price' as t FROM ID_list
)
SELECT IDs, string_agg(CASE IDs WHEN CTE.IDs THEN CTE.t
                        end::text, ';') as price
FROM table
LEFT JOIN CTE cte.IDs=table.IDs
GROUP BY IDs
ORDER BY IDs
```

Comment: for something like that to work you need dynamic sql

Comment: A fiddle to work with would be very helpful. And always disclose your version of Postgres, please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a document type like [`json`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) or [`hstore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html) as stepping stone:

Basic query:

```sql
SELECT t.ids
     , to_json(t.*) ->> (t.ids || '_price') AS price
FROM   tbl t;
```

[`to_json()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) converts the whole row to a JSON object, which you can then pick a (dynamically concatenated) key from.

Your aggregation:

```sql
SELECT t.ids
     , string_agg(to_json(t.*) ->> (t.ids || '_price'), ';') AS prices
FROM   tbl t
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Converting the whole (big?) row adds some overhead, but you have to read the whole table for your query anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A union would be one approach here:

```sql
SELECT IDs, A_Price FROM yourTable WHERE A_Price IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT IDs, B_Price FROM yourTable WHERE B_Price IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT IDs, C_Price FROM yourTable WHERE C_Price IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you. In this case I still have to type A_price, B_price, C_price manually. since I have a very wide list, it would not be efficient.